# How to select a near by face without its center being in view?

Tags: selection-tools

I have a big model and I am zoomed in the view, so I can not see the center of a face. Usually I select a face in Edit mode by clicking its center dot. But how can I select a face, let us say by nearest to mouse point. The images below show the situation (Unselected, Selected, Center of face).

Edit: It turns out selection with RMB is not working only for my model, I will check what might be the reason for this.

[image: Unselected]
[image: Selected]
[image: Center of face]

Blender 2.77

Comment: If you activate the mesh select mode "face" you just (right) click on any face area, it should be selected...

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for faces which extend the view. When the face is fully in view I can Right-Click or press B to select with a box.

Comment: could you share an example blend (eg with: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) , with the view set as you say?

Comment: You are right it is working with a new model but not in my complex model which I can not share here. I will have a look deeper to be able to reproduce what might make the problem.

Comment: ok. check doubles, normals, loops... too.

Comment: The mesh has a couple of Boolean operators in it, but I can not detect any problems. But thanks for your quick suggestions.